# How does Linux Manage the Termination of Sessions?

Tags: linux, rhel, security, session

I understand that maxlogins can be configured to limit the number of concurrent sessions in /etc/security/limits.conf or /etc/security/limits.d/*.conf.

Example:

- hard maxlogins 10

Let's say I want to set it higher, like 100. How does Linux manage the termination of sessions? If the user is disconnected, what does Linux do with the session ID's, and how does one ensure the sessions are terminated?

Answer (score 0):

Linux doesn't decide to terminate sessions because of the *.conf files.  While logins are at the limit, Linux simply refuses new sessions.

Comment: I understand that. Perhaps the question is not clear. Regardless of the configuration, when users disconnect, how does Linux terminate sessions and handle the session ID's?

The implication being that if up to 100 concurrent sessions are allowed, there could be greater risk of a DoS.